# How to override the existing from address of SMTP configurations defined in config.groovy

Tags: email, grails, grails-2.0

I have grails 2.0 and [mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail/) installed, and I have configured SMTP in confi.groovy as follows

```
grails {
mail {
  host = "smtp.gmail.com"
  port = 465
  username = "mymail@gmail.com  "
  password = "mypwd"
  props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
           "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
           "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
           "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
}
```

}

And in one of my controller I am doing as follows

```
sendMail {
  from "Vinay <mymail@gmail.com>"
  to "fred@g2one.com"
  subject "Hello John"
  html '<b>Hello</b> World'
}
```

But when i receive mail the from address "mymail". Grails is still using the username of the smtp config, How to override this So that I can have customized 'from' address

Answer (score 5):

Grails is in fact doing the correct thing and passing your specified From line to the SMTP server, but it's a "feature" of GMail authenticated SMTP that it only allows From addresses that are registered "addresses I own" in the GMail account.  If you try and use a From address that isn't one of your registered aliases then the from address Grails supplied will be ignored by GMail and the SMTP server will replace it with the main address of the account that was used to authenticate.

If you have a known fixed set of from addresses you will be using then you can simply add them all to your GMail account settings, but it's not possible to use an arbitrary From address with GMail SMTP.